# SQL Server stored procedure transfer an attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working on some example questions in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I am very lost on this question, if anyone could explain how to go about transferring an attribute like that I would appreciate it. I'll attach the tables of a simple database that I'm testing with.

> Create a stored procedure that accepts an `AreaID` and a `handlerID`. The procedure will transfer an area from one Handler to another.
>
> When the area is transferred the new Handler will have $25.00 added their Salary and the old Handler will have $25.00 subtracted from their Salary.
>
> Remember to update all tables as needed as well as include a transaction and error catching

Code:

```
Create Table Runner
(
    RunnerID int identity (1,1) not null
    Constraint PK_Runner primary key clustered,     
    RunnerFirstName varchar(30) not null,
    RunnerLastName varchar(30) not null,
    Phone char(10) not null
    Constraint ck_Phone check (Phone like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)

Create Table DevSite
(
    DevSiteId int not null
    Constraint PK_DevSite primary key clustered,
    DevSiteName varchar(50) not null,
    DevSiteAddress varchar(60) not null
)

Create Table Handler
(
    handlerID int identity (1,1) not null
    Constraint PK_Handler primary key clustered,
    HandlerFirstName varchar(30) not null,
    HandlerLastName varchar(30) not null,
    PagerNumber char(10) not null
    Constraint ck_pager check (PagerNumber like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
    Salary smallmoney not null Constraint CK_Salary check(Salary >= 0) Constraint df_Salary default 12.00 
)

Create Table Area
(
    AreaID int not null
    Constraint PK_Area primary key clustered,
    AreaName varchar(50) not null,
    AreaSupeFirstName varchar(30) not null,
    AreaSupeLastName varchar(30) not null,
    handlerID int not null constraint fk_AreaToHandler references Handler(handlerID)
)

Create Table Direction
(
    DirectionID int not null Constraint PK_Direction primary key clustered,
    DirectionName varchar(50) not null,
    EstimatedTime varchar(3) not null,
    AreaID int not null Constraint FK_RouteToArea references Area (AreaID), 
    DevSiteID int not null Constraint FK_RouteToDevSite references DevSite (DevSiteID),
    RunnerId int not null Constraint FK_RouteToRunner references Runner (RunnerId)
)

Create Table Consumer
(
    ConsumerID int not null     Constraint PK_Consumer primary key clustered,
    ConsumerFirstName varchar(30) not null,
    ConsumerLastName varchar(30) not null,
    Address varchar(50) not null,
    City varchar(30) not null,
    Province char(2) not null Constraint ck_province check (Province Like '[A-Z][A-Z]') Constraint DF_Province Default 'AB',
    PC char(7) not null Constraint CK_PostalCode Check (PC Like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]'),
    PrePaidTip smallmoney not null Constraint ck_prepaidtip check (PrepaidTip >=0) Constraint DF_PrepaidTip Default 0,
    RouteID int not null Constraint FK_ConsumerToDirection references Direction (DirectionID)
)

Create Table DeliveryType 
(
    DeliveryTypeID smallint not null Constraint PK_DelieverType primary key clustered,
    DeliveryTypeDescription varchar(10) not null,
    DeliveryTypeCharge smallmoney not null
)

Create Table Paper
(
    PaperId smallint identity (1,1) not null Constraint PK_Paper primary key clustered, 
    PaperDescription varchar(30) not null
)

Create Table ConsumerPaper 
(
    ConsumerID int not null Constraint FK_ConsumerPaperToConsumer references Consumer (ConsumerId),
    PaperID smallint not null Constraint FK_ConsumerPaperToPaper references Paper (PaperId),
    DeliveryTypeID smallint not null Constraint FK_ConsumerPaperToDeliveryType references DeliveryType (DeliveryTypeId),
    Constraint  PK_ConsumerPaper_ConsumerID_PaperID primary key clustered (ConsumerID, PaperID)
)



CREATE PROCEDURE TransferHandler 
    (@HandlerIdOne INT = NULL, 
     @HandlerIdTwo INT = NULL, 
     @AreaID INT = NULL) 
AS
    -- guard clause - if something is wrong, call RAISERROR which 
    -- stops execution - no need to use "else" after that
    IF @DHandleridone is NULL OR @Handleridtwo IS NULL OR @AreaID IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('Missing parameter, please enter "id one" "id two" "area id" ', 16, 1)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        -- update the first part
        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET Salary = Salary - 25.00
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdOne

        -- update the second part    
        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET Salary = Salary + 25.00
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdTwo

        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET AreaID = null
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdOne


        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET AreaID = @AreaID
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdTwo

        -- if all goes well - commit the transaction    
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- if an error occurred - show the error details
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

        -- roll back the transaction    
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
```

Comment: Is said "if anyone could explain how to go about transferring an attribute like that I would appreciate it". I am stuck on how to transfer the attribute. I understand how to raiserror for parameters and update the salary. Its specifically transferring an attribute. Do I just null one and alter the other? ect.

Comment: I thought that adding what i'm working on specifically would help people understand where i'm coming from as I find a lot of the answers i'm looking for are far beyond my coding ability. Sorry if it sounded as if I was asking others to complete it for me.

Comment: But I'm sure you've been trying to get this to work - so you most likely have some bits of code for that stored procedure - right? Post it here! We'll help, but we won't just write all the code for you

Comment: I added the code that I have to the bottom, I have deleted quite a bit of what I messing around with as it was all over the place.

Comment: OK - now we're getting somewhere! So the **amount** is not being passed in as a parameter?

Comment: I don't believe so, unless I have to declare it and i'm totally off in what I think im doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you could try something like this - using the `TRY-CATCH` feature available in SQL Server 2005 and newer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TransferHandler 
    (@HandlerIdOne INT = NULL, 
     @HandlerIdTwo INT = NULL, 
     @AreaID INT = NULL) 
AS
    -- guard clause - if something is wrong, call RAISERROR which 
    -- stops execution - no need to use "else" after that
    IF @DHandleridone is NULL OR @Handleridtwo IS NULL OR @AreaID IS NULL
        RAISERROR ('Missing parameter, please enter "id one" "id two" "area id" ', 16, 1)

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        -- update the first part
        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET Salary = Salary - 25.00, 
            AreaId = NULL
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdOne

        -- update the second part    
        UPDATE dbo.handler
        SET Salary = Salary + 25.00,
            AreaID = @AreaID
        WHERE handlerid = @HandlerIdTwo

        -- if all goes well - commit the transaction    
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- if an error occurred - show the error details
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
            ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

        -- roll back the transaction    
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
```

Comment: This works for my salary editing but I'm still lost on how to transfer the area from one Handler to another.

Comment: @Thunderous: yes - but you don't need two separate `UPDATE` just for the `AreaID` - you can easily update more than one column in a single `UPDATE` statement - see my updated response